How to use RAG with conversation history for follow up questions?
I am building custom AI chatbot service where user can upload pdf, docx, web pages, etc and I create a custom AI chatbot using RAG.
For follow up questions I try to repharse the question based on conversation history and then use that to retrieve context and then answer the question.
This is little slow because there are 2 api calls but works pretty good to answer follow up questions. My probem is when the user input is not a question, it's something like "hi", "ok", "thank you", etc.
These are not question now first call produces response to these but how do i differentiate between questions and such conversational words so that I can end my task after 1 call for these.
Right now for these keywords the chatbot just goes off the track.
Please let me know for any workarounds or suggestions.

I faced a similar problem and came up with a solution: I made an 'observer bot'. It's like a chatbot watching other chatbots, staying neutral. I taught it to tell if a question was asked or not. If it was a question, it would say 'questionTrue'; if not, 'questionFalse'. This way, I didn't have to use my RAG model when it wasn't needed. I hope this idea helps you too.

Thanks Mubashir - I tried doing that but sometimes it provides some additional information like why questionTrue or questionFalse. I assume you must have mentioned something  "only respond with questionTrue or questionFalse based on the provided chat history or user's last message". Later, you will compare the response if user asked the question or not.  Also, in that case you will be making 3 calls which can slow down the response time. For e.g. First you'll ask if it is a question or not. Second, we will generate a standalone question and in the 3rd call you will reply the end user.

can you share your prompts, i got the same problem and did not get good results when the chat history has various topics.

You can create a response grading function that assesses whether a given response is a question. The grader can be tailored to your specific requirements. This way, you can filter out irrelevant and redundant messages from your chat history.
An example of how to write a Grader function:
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain_community.chat_models import ChatOllama
from langchain_core.output_parsers import JsonOutputParser
    
#LLM
llm = ChatOllama(model=local_llm, format="json", temperature=0) 
prompt = PromptTemplate( template="""<|begin_of_text|><|start_header_id|>system<|end_header_id|> You are a grader assessing relevance 
  of a retrieved document to a user question. If the document contains keywords related to the user question, 
  grade it as relevant. It does not need to be a stringent test. The goal is to filter out erroneous retrievals. \n
  Give a binary score 'yes' or 'no' score to indicate whether the document is relevant to the question. \n 
  Provide the binary score as a JSON with a single key 'score' and no premable or explaination. 
  <|eot_id|><|start_header_id|>user<|end_header_id|> Here is the retrieved document: \n\n {document} \n\n 
  Here is the user question: {question} \n <|eot_id|><|start_header_id|>assistant<|end_header_id|> 
  """,
  input_variables=["question", "document"],
)
retrieval_grader = prompt | llm | JsonOutputParser() 
question = "what is Iceland's healthy life expectancy?" 
docs = retriever.invoke(question)
doc_txt = docs[1].page_content
print(retrieval_grader.invoke({"question": question, "document": doc_txt }))

This will return a JSON object like
{ 'score': <yes/no> } 

Depending on the response you can take the decision

Thanks for sharing. Very useful prompt.
Few tweaks needed here ,
Line :
 docs = retriever.invoke(question)

To be modified as:
llm.invoke(question)

Line:
doc_txt = docs[1].page_content

To be modified as:
 doc_txt = docs.content

With this two modification , this prompt is providing very meaningful binary response , will be very helpful for vector search in dbs.

This is one of the common issues when you try to implement the follow up questions.
In my case , Hard prompting worked. You can make a separate LLM call to understand the intent of the input i.e. whether it is a question or not.
